# R: Overlay using functions containing if/else statements

Tags: raster, r, overlay

I have two rasters, `x` and `y`, and I'd like to do calculations with them using the `overlay` function. For example,

```
MyFun <- function(x, y) x * y
res <- overlay(x, y, fun = MyFun)
```

This seems to work fine. Now, I want to add a conditional statement to my function like this:

```
MyFun <- function(x, y) {
    if(x > 0){ 
        x * y
    }else{
        abs(x) * y
    }
}
```

This gives a warning message like below:

```
Warning messages:
1: In if (x > 0) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Clearly, R isn't happy with my code.

How should I write conditional statements in my functions so that they are compatible with `overlay` and rasters?

**NB** This is a toy example. My real task is more complicated, but the principle is the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `ifelse` as an alternative to `if` and `else` blocks in a function. You can nest multiple statements in an `ifelse` and if you are trying to vectorize a problem, it is much cleaner. Note that an absolute `abs` statement on a zero value still returns zero so, I just used a very small number as a constant.

```
library(raster)
x <- raster(nrows=100, ncols=100)
  x[] <- runif(ncell(x))
y <- raster(nrows=100, ncols=100)
  y[] <- runif(ncell(y))

myFun <- function(x, y, p = 1.0e-08) { ifelse( x > 0, x * y, ifelse(x <= p * y)) }
( res <- overlay(stack(x, y), fun = myFun) )
```

Answer (score 1):

A vectorized form would be

```
MyFun <- function(x, y) {
    i <- x < 0 
    x[i] <- abs(x) * y
    x[!i] <- x * y 
    x
}
```

But it might be more efficient (and certainly less error prone) to do

```
MyFun <- function(x, y) abs(x) * y
res <- overlay(x, y, fun = MyFun)
```

Or simply

```
res <- abs(x) * y
```