# Raster Calculation with 2 Raster Layers

Tags: raster, r, overlay

I am attempting to create a new raster layer based on the values of one raster layer using a formula that is conditional based on the values in another layer.

Two source layers:

```
> ndvi
class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 7741, 7611, 58916751  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 30, 30  (x, y)
extent      : 580185, 808515, 4191885, 4424115  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=utm +zone=15 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
data source : C:/Users/xxx/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpScc57V/raster/r_tmp_2019-04-22_112901_2168_61926.grd 
names       : layer 
values      : -1, 1  (min, max)

> pv
class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 7741, 7611, 58916751  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 30, 30  (x, y)
extent      : 580185, 808515, 4191885, 4424115  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=utm +zone=15 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
data source : C:/Users/xxx/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpScc57V/raster/r_tmp_2019-04-22_112936_2168_54474.grd 
names       : layer 
values      : 0, 1  (min, max)
```

Layers each have the same dimensions, projection, and extent.

I want to create a new layer, e, that has the value:

```
0.97 when ndvi < 0.2
0.004 * pv + 0.986 when ndvi >= 0.2 and ndvi <= 0.5
0.99 when ndvi > 0.5
```

My statement is:

```
e <- overlay(ndvi, pv, fun = function(ndvi, pv)
    {
        ifelse(ndvi < 0.2, 0.97, ifelse(ndvi > 0.5, 0.99, 0.004 * pv + 0.986))
    }
)
```

However, when I execute this, I receive the error:

> Error in ifelse(ndvi > 0.5, 0.99, 0.004 * pv + 0.986) :    argument
>   "pv" is missing, with no default

How can I write this function so that it is compatible with overlay()?  Is another approach more appropriate?

I'm somewhat new to R.

**Other permutations attempted:**

```
calc_e <- function(ndvi, pv)
    {
        ifelse(ndvi < 0.2, 0.97, ifelse(ndvi <= 0.5, 0.004 * pv + 0.986, 0.99))
    }

e <- overlay(ndvi, pv, fun = calc_e)
```

Same error was returned.

Then I tried:

```
ndvi_2 <- ndvi
ndvi_2[ndvi_2 < 0.2] <- 0.92

ndvi_m <- ndvi
ndvi_m[ndvi_m >= 0.2 && ndvi_m <= 0.5] <- 0.004 * pv + 0.986

ndvi_5 <- ndvi
ndvi_5[ndvi_5 > 0.5] <- 0.99
```

The first and third subset assignments ran.  However, I received an error on the second one "ndvi_m[ndvi_m >= 0.2 && ndvi_m <= 0.5] <- 0.004 * pv + 0.986"

> Error in ndvi_m >= 0.2 && ndvi_m <= 0.5 : invalid 'x' type in 'x && y'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [R: Overlay using functions containing if/else statements](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/197475/r-overlay-using-functions-containing-if-else-statements)

Comment: I did see that question/answer prior to posting my question.  I even temporarily updated my syntax to use stack() as was used in that question's answer.  However, I received the same error and subsequently reverted my syntax.

Comment: I would define your function outside of the `overlay` similar to the other answer for starters. As another troubleshooting step, I'd create separate rasters matching your conditions e.g. `ndvi2=ndvi  ndvi2[ndvi2<0.2]=0.92` see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51716315/how-to-subset-classify-raster-based-on-another-raster-grid-cells-values

Comment: I separated out the function, but the error remained.  I will continue with your next suggestion.

Comment: So the subset returning an error has no way to reference pv since it's only a ndvi raster. If you think of rasters as a grid of cells, then you have a bunch of ndvi cells. Your pv raster is a bunch of pv cells in a separate raster.  so this is where a 
raster stack would come in handy - think of it as a raster sandwich where you want to look at the meat (ndvi) and the lettuce (pv) as a whole sandwich (rasterstack)

Comment: I would also make sure that if your pv value = 0 that your formula gives you the result you want aka 0.986

Comment: Thanks.  That does make sense regarding the subset on ndvi_m and no reference to pv.  I also know how to create the stack with ndvi and pv as layers.  What I don't know how to do is to navigate the stack and apply the appropriate formula based on the values of one layer and the condition of the other.

Comment: Take a close read of calc and overlay help. Your calc_e function is written incorrectly and does not index the two variables, thus the missing argument error.

Comment: The solution was to use the function as defined by GISKid and pass that with the raster stack to calc() instead of overlay().  Thank you!

Comment: Please write your solution as an answer and remove it from your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
recalc<-function(ndvi,pv){
  ifelse(ndvi<0.2,0.92,ifelse(ndvi >= 0.2 & ndvi <= 0.5,0.004 * pv + 0.986,ifelse(ndvi >0.5,0.99,NA)))
}

r<-stack(ndvi,pv)
res <- overlay(r, fun = recalc)
```

As per updated comment the solution that worked was instead using `calc`:

```
res<-calc(r,fun=recalc)
```

The recalc function is basically saying : 
If ndvi < 0.2, assign 0.92, if not look at this new ifelse based on these other conditions, assign this new value using this formula, if it doesn't meet this condition try ndvi >0.5 and assign 0.99 for anything that doesn't match those conditions assign it a value of "NA".

Comment: Same error.  I'm beginning to wonder if it is something in the data.  I need to dig further into that.

Comment: Try adding a ... argument in the recalc function. You do not actually need to do anything with it as it is providing a passthrough to overlay.

Answer (score 2):

With help from @GISKid and @JeffreyEvans, the solution that finally worked was a combination of both of their comments.

```
calc_e = function(x) {
    return(
            ifelse(
                    x[1] < 0.2,
                    0.97,
                    ifelse(
                            x[1] >= 0.2 && x[1] <= 0.5,
                            0.004 + x[2] * 0.986,
                            ifelse(
                                    x[1] > 0.5,
                                    0.99,
                                    NA
    )))) }

e <- calc(stack(ndvi, pv), fun = calc_e)
```